# Dynamically registered broadcast receiver's onReceive() hook method is not called

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging, broadcastreceiver, android-service

This is part of an optional assignment. I have an Activity dynamically registering a broadcast receiver and also starting an IntentService. The broadcast receiver is supposed to receive the intent from the IntentService after it performs its work. However, after the IntentService sent the broadcast, the onReceive is not called.

I was logging the output, and the last log I receive is from the IntentService after it sends the broadcast. After that, I have no idea how to continue debugging.

Please advice.

What is wrong with my code such that the onReceive() method is not called?

---

EDIT: ANSWER (from HeyAlex)

The IntentService was sending broadcast via the LocalBroadcastManager, while the Broadcast receiver started by the Activity was not registered to LocalBroadcastManager instance but the normal dynamic register. So the broadcast receiver did not pick up on the sent broadcast.

---

DownloadAtomFeedService (extending IntentService)

```
  @Override
public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    List<Entry> entries = downloadAtomFeed(uri.toString());

    int requestCode = intent.getExtras().getInt(REQUEST_CODE);

    sendEntries((ArrayList<Entry>) entries,uri,requestCode);
    Log.d(TAG, "onHandleIntent: returning to MainActivity");
}


private void sendEntries(ArrayList<Entry> entries,
                         Uri url,
                         int requestCode) {

    Bundle bundle = makeReplyBundle(entries,url,requestCode);

    Intent intent = new MainActivity().makeBroadcastReceiverIntent();
    intent.putExtras(bundle);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
    Log.d(TAG, "sendEntries: SENT BROADCAST");
}

private Bundle makeReplyBundle(ArrayList<Entry> entries,
                               Uri url,
                               int requestCode) {

    Bundle data = new Bundle();

    data.putParcelableArrayList(ENTRY_ARRAY_KEY,entries);

    data.putInt(REQUEST_CODE,requestCode);

    data.putString(FEED_URL,url.toString());

    if(entries == null){
        data.putInt(DOWNLOAD_RESULTS,Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
    }else data.putInt(DOWNLOAD_RESULTS,Activity.RESULT_OK);

    return data;
}
```

MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(DownloadStateReceiver.BROADCAST_ACTION);

    DownloadStateReceiver mDownloadStateReceiver = new DownloadStateReceiver();

    registerReceiver(mDownloadStateReceiver,intentFilter);
    android.util.Log.d(TAG, "onResume: downloadstatereceiver registered");
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).unregisterReceiver(mDownloadStateReceiver);

    super.onPause();
}


public static Intent makeBroadcastReceiverIntent() {

    Intent intent = new Intent().setAction(DownloadStateReceiver.BROADCAST_ACTION);
    return intent;
}


public class DownloadStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
   public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION =
            "myassignment.activities.BROADCAST";

    public DownloadStateReceiver() {
        android.util.Log.d(TAG, "DownloadStateReceiver: ");
    }

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        MainActivity.this.serviceIntentReceived(intent.getExtras());
        android.util.Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: BroadcastReceived");
    }
}
```

Comment: better to publish a full example

Comment: @HeyAlex I can't upload the full example due to some rules. Can I email you instead? Please check your email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you're registering BroadcastReceiver not by LocalBroadcastManager. Just make your onResume like:

```
 @Override
 protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(DownloadStateReceiver.BROADCAST_ACTION);
    mDownloadStateReceiver = new DownloadStateReceiver();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mDownloadStateReceiver,intentFilter);
    android.util.Log.d(TAG, "onResume: downloadstatereceiver registered");
}
```